# HEVC/x265 intra encoding of the very 1st CTU

Tags: video, encoding, video-processing, video-encoding, hevc

How HEVC/x265 encoders are manipulate the encoding of the very 1st CTU of the I-Frame (reference) at the most top left,  since there are no neighbouring CTUs (samples) available ?

Answer (score 0):

Border CUs use the padded margin of frame as their reference. I think the intensity level of margin pixels is 2^(bitDepth-1).

I don't remember about HM, but in VTM, it is implemented in function `xFillReferenceSamples` with the following code: `const Pel valueDC = 1 << (sps.getBitDepth( chType ) - 1)`

Comment: what exactly do you mean "padded margin". Can you give me an example or link my to an extended documentation ?

Comment: The intensity level of all reference pixels that fall out of frame borders, is replaced with 2^(bitDepth-1). For example, for an 8-bit sequence, we use 128. (This is called padding in image processing)

Comment: I don't remember about HM, but in VTM, it is implemented in function ``xFillReferenceSamples`` with the following code: ``const Pel   valueDC   = 1 << (sps.getBitDepth( chType ) - 1);``

Comment: what is VTM  you are mention of?

Comment: VVC Test Model (VTM) is the reference software of the Versatile Video Coding (VVC), which is the successor of High Efficiency Video Coding (HEVC). Look it up.